# How to generate a set of points that are equidistant from each other and lie on a normal distribution

Tags: geometry, gaussian

I am trying to generate n points on a normal distribution(say, mean \mu and standard deviation \sigma) that are equidistant(Let's say the distance between pints is d) from each other in C. Points at normal distribution are from (-3\sigma + \mu) to (3\sigma + \mu). I am trying to have beads on the Gaussian curve, where beads are at equal distance (curved length).

Thank you in advance for the answer.

Comment: What does it mean for points to be "on a normal distribution"? Are you intending to graph the function
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}
$$
or something?

Comment: @MattiP. yes, I am trying to generate equidistant points on this function.

Comment: Bad news: In general, the length of a curve is not integrable in closed form, which means no luck doing this analytically.

Comment: What do you mean with "generate"? Just substitute the equidistant $x$ into the formula and you are done.

Comment: Do you mean Euclidian distance?

Comment: @Moti 'equidistant by arc length'

Comment: You can make this task substantially easier by drawing the points at constant intervals along the $x$-axis, instead of using the arc length. How would that sound to you? This way, the problem becomes basically trivial and visually, it would look only slightly different (at least if you have more than a few points).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curve length of a function in $x$ can be found as

$$\ell_f(a, b) =\int_a^b \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{df(x)}{dx}\right)^2}dx$$

Which is nasty enough that in general we don't get an integrable result out of it; in our case we need to perform the integral *and then invert it*, and this is a recipe for sadness.

So what we'll do instead of this is do it numerically, replacing integration with the Riemann sum and differentiation with the difference quotient and doing a little simplifying.

$$\ell_f(a, b) = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \sum_{t=\frac{a}{\Delta x} + 1}^{\frac{b}{\Delta x}}\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\left(f(t\Delta x)-f((t-1)\Delta x)\right)^2}$$

Which still looks kinda mean but is possible to plug & chug by picking a reasonable value for $\Delta x$.

Of course, that only works forward, and we have to work backwards.  Our best bet, since this is a series, is to do linear interpolation: draw straight lines between the points that make up the series.  This gives a monotonic piecewise linear function, which is trivial to invert.

### The procedure

We have our function $f(x)$, a low and high end of the interval in question $p$ and $q$, and a number of intervals to break the function into $n$.

Calculate $\Delta x = \frac{q-p}{n}$

For each integer $k$, $x_k = a + k\Delta x$, $y_k = f(x_k)$.

$d_k = \sqrt{(x_k - x_{k-1})^2 + (y_k - y_{k-1})^2} = \sqrt{\Delta x^2 + (y_k - y_{k-1})^2} $

$\ell_k = \sum_{i=1}^{k} d_k$

$m_k = \frac{\Delta x}{d_k}$

$b_k = x_k - \ell_k m_k$

And now we have a piecewise linear function: $x_f(\ell) = m_k \ell + b_k \text{ for } x_{k-1} \le \ell < x_k$

Now we wish to place $m$ spaces between points, so we take values $\frac{\ell_ni}{m}$ for $i$ in $0 \le i \le m$, find their $x$ values from the piecewise linear function above, and then from there the $f(x)$ values.

### Example

Our star today is the standard normal distribution density function, $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

over the interval $-3 \le x \le 3$. I'll use $n = 6$ here for relative brevity and for relatively nice $x$ values.

| $x$ | $y$ | $d$ | $\ell$ | $m$ | $b$ | formula | interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $-3$ | $0.004432$ |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| $-2$ | $0.053991$ | $1.001227$ | $1.001227$ | $0.998774$ | $-3.000000$ | $0.998774\times \ell -3.000000$ | $0.000000\le \ell < 1.001227$ |
| $-1$ | $0.241971$ | $1.017515$ | $2.018742$ | $0.982787$ | $-2.983993$ | $0.982787\times \ell -2.983993$ | $1.001227\le \ell < 2.018742$ |
| $0$ | $0.398942$ | $1.012245$ | $3.030987$ | $0.987903$ | $-2.994322$ | $0.987903\times \ell -2.994322$ | $2.018742\le \ell < 3.030987$ |
| $1$ | $0.241971$ | $1.012245$ | $4.043232$ | $0.987903$ | $-2.994322$ | $0.987903\times \ell -2.994322$ | $3.030987\le \ell < 4.043232$ |
| $2$ | $0.053991$ | $1.017515$ | $5.060747$ | $0.982787$ | $-2.973635$ | $0.982787\times \ell -2.973635$ | $4.043232\le \ell < 5.060747$ |
| $3$ | $0.004432$ | $1.001227$ | $6.061974$ | $0.998774$ | $-3.054544$ | $0.998774\times \ell -3.054544$ | $5.060747\le \ell < 6.061974$ |

at this point I want to point something out: the curve length of this function is only about 1% more than the width of our interval in $x$.  There isn't going to be much difference between evenly spaced on $x$ and evenly spaced along the curve!  In fact when we get our points, the largest difference between the two is about $0.008$.  Still, the point here is a reasonably general procedure, so let's continue.

Now that we've got our piecewise linear function, we'll just plug in evenly-spaced $\ell$ values.

| $\ell$ | $x$ | $y$ |  | $\ell$ | $x$ | $y$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $0.000000$ | $-3.000000$ | $0.004432$ |  | $3.030987$ | $0.000000$ | $0.398942$ |
| $0.303099$ | $-2.697273$ | $0.010498$ |  | $3.334086$ | $0.299432$ | $0.381453$ |
| $0.606197$ | $-2.394546$ | $0.022689$ |  | $3.637185$ | $0.598864$ | $0.333452$ |
| $0.909296$ | $-2.091818$ | $0.044744$ |  | $3.940283$ | $0.898296$ | $0.266493$ |
| $1.212395$ | $-1.792467$ | $0.080026$ |  | $4.243382$ | $1.196705$ | $0.194954$ |
| $1.515494$ | $-1.494586$ | $0.130572$ |  | $4.546481$ | $1.494586$ | $0.130572$ |
| $1.818592$ | $-1.196705$ | $0.194954$ |  | $4.849579$ | $1.792467$ | $0.080026$ |
| $2.121691$ | $-0.898296$ | $0.266493$ |  | $5.152678$ | $2.091818$ | $0.044744$ |
| $2.424790$ | $-0.598864$ | $0.333452$ |  | $5.455777$ | $2.394546$ | $0.022689$ |
| $2.727888$ | $-0.299432$ | $0.381453$ |  | $5.758876$ | $2.697273$ | $0.010498$ |
|  |  |  |  | $6.061974$ | $3.000000$ | $0.004432$ |

And we can plot these.

[image: 21 points evenly spaced along the normal distribution]

Comment: could you please tell how m_k is generated in the table since the m_k expression is \delta x * d_k does not match with the values given in the table. Also could you please inform me how to generalise it for general mean and variance. What changes I need to make there?

Comment: ah, typesetting error, I had the braces but not the \frac